# Pulp to pyomo transition of conditional snippet

Tags: pyomo

I need to migrate a piece from PULP to pyomo. My Pulp code snippet is below. It basically is filtering possible and impossible combination before converting it to variable.

```
feasible_set = [(a, b) for a in food_type for b in specimen_type if condition satisfied]                 
not_feasible_set= [(a, b) for a in food_type for b in specimen_type if (a,b) not in feasible_set]

allocate = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", feasible_set, 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)        
allocate.update(pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", not_feasible_set, 0, 0, pulp.LpInteger))
```

How can I write the same in pyomo using `pyomo.environ.Var`?

Comment: Before we get to translating to `pyomo`, why are you extending your variable `allocate` in this manner where many instances of the variable is trivial...  max = min = 0.  This should not be needed in a proper formulation.

Comment: @AirSquid because my constraint in the code don't distinguish between feasible and not feasible set...

Answer (score 1):

On the first point about feeding the constraint trivial variables...  just don't do it.  :)  You only need to construct constraints for active (or "legal") instances of your variables, so you need to be pretty adroit at making subsets.  In the example below, I use some data to make a set of "prohibited" values and exclude them from the constraint construction.  There are MANY variations of this.  I could have (at the start) just made a set of the *legal* combinations with a similar construct and used that if that made sense.  If the "prohibited" values are only relative to this constraint and not universal, this method works.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

prohib_combos = {('veggie', 3), ('dairy', 2)}

mdl = pyo.ConcreteModel()

mdl.food_type = pyo.Set(initialize={'veggie', 'meat', 'dairy'})
mdl.specimen_type = pyo.Set(initialize=[1,2,3])

mdl.allocate = pyo.Var(mdl.food_type, mdl.specimen_type, domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

mdl.prohibited = pyo.Set(within=mdl.food_type * mdl.specimen_type, 
    initialize=prohib_combos)


def c1(self, food, specimen):
    return mdl.allocate[food, specimen] <= 2
legal_combos = [ (f, s) for f in mdl.food_type for s in mdl.specimen_type
                    if (f, s) not in mdl.prohibited]
mdl.c1 = pyo.Constraint(legal_combos, rule=c1)

mdl.pprint()
```